# How to pass an object with a MVC ajax form to controller

Tags: ajaxform, asp.net-mvc-5, ajax.beginform

Hi I have the following Razor View:

```
@model AgonConFF.ViewModels.ClaimModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DataCaptureNew", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result", OnBegin = "onBegin()", OnComplete = "onComplate()" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Origin.SourceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control CapInput", placeholder = "Source Name" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Origin.SourceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @*Source Name*@

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Origin.MailFax, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control CapInput", placeholder = "Mail Address / Fax Nr" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Origin.MailFax, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @*Mail Address / Fax Nr*@

    <input type="submit" value="Capture" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

my JS looks like this:

```
function onBegin() {
    $('#loading').show();
}

function onComplate() {
    $('#loading').hide();
}
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
//Action method that handles the testCreate form submission
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult DataCaptureNew(ClaimModel origin)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       db.Origins.Add(origin.Origin);
       origin.Origin.OriginID = 1;
       db.SaveChanges();
       return PartialView("testPartial", origin);
    }

    return PartialView("testPartial", origin);
}
```

When I submit my form and check inside the controller with a break point I see that the `ClaimModel origin`'s relevant object is null and gives me an error. This post works perfectly when I'm just using an `Html.BeginForm`. In that case the `Origin` object passes through just fine. How can I pass this object through using `Ajax.BeginForm`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar requirement and I will share what worked for me in this case. I basically used `Form data serialization`. Also I used `Html.BeginForm` so I am modifying the above code accordingly.

**Step 1**
Assign an id to your form. I have used `"claim_form"`.Add a button and give an id to that as well.I used `id="click"` below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "claim_form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Origin.SourceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control CapInput", placeholder = "Source Name" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Origin.SourceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Origin.MailFax, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control CapInput", placeholder = "Mail Address / Fax Nr" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Origin.MailFax, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    <input type="submit" value="Capture" class="btn btn-default" />
    <input type="button" id="click" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

**Step 2:**
Ajax Call

```
$('#click').click(function(e) {


               //Say your controller is ClaimController
                var url = '@Url.Action("DataCaptureNew","ClaimController")';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data:$("#claim_form").serialize(),

                   //no need to give the content -type here
                    success: function(data) {

                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                    }

                });

            });
```

**Step 3:** Modify your controller method for Model Binding

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult DataCaptureNew(FormCollection col)
    {

        //Model Binding usimg TryUpdateModel
        var testClaim = new ClaimModel();
        var tstVal = TryUpdateModel<ClaimModel>(testClaim ,col);
        //namespace for ClaimModel here say it is AgonConFF.ViewModels.ClaimModel
        var claim1 = Type.GetType("AgonConFF.ViewModels.ClaimModel");
        //While debugging you will b eable to see how claim2 gets updated with the fields from formCollection
        var claim2= Activator.CreateInstance(claim1);

        var binder = Binders.GetBinder(claim1);

        var bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext()
        {
                ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => claim2, claim1),
                ModelState = ModelState,
                ValueProvider = col
        };

        binder.BindModel(ControllerContext, bindingContext);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Model is valid here");
        }


       return Json(claim2);

    }
```

**Note: claim2 should have the required model.**
**I am returning a Json result from the method.You can retrieve the Json result and render it in a partial view.**